# EXCEL VBA - Populating last Row with database new data only

Tags: vba, excel

So i have a database that i update it daily and i want to populate a sheet with only the tickets that had been breached.
What i want to do is to check on the database and copy only the new tickets to that sheet right after the last value.

My code now is copying all the tickets avaiable and i wanted to change that.

Can anyone help? Thank you

Here is my code so far

```
'SELECT DATABASE SHEET
Sheets("RAW ALL INC").Select

'FILTER ONLY THE BROKEN TICKETS
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$X$1312").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="TRUE"

'COPY ALL TICKETS (THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO SELECT ONLY NEW TICKETS)
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

'PASTE THE TICKETS ON THE BROKEN TICKETS SHEET
Sheets("Broken Justification").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Is there a unique identifier for the tickets so you could determine whether the broken tickets sheet already contains the ticket you might want to copy?

Comment: without some sample data this is difficult to do, but using my Imagination here, I think you need to get the address of the current value showing and copy just that.

Comment: All the tickets have unique numbers, like for exemple:

INC1444333
INC1445161
INC1445169
INC1445172
INC1445269
INC1438889
INC1446692
INC1446317
INC1445895
INC1448599
INC1447130
INC1445163
INC1446468
INC1447147

That way if i can make a loop to check if the number is already on that sheet, i would just skip it

Answer (score 1):

I think you can select just the visible cells after you apply your auto-filter, like this:

```
Sub filtersub()
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$X$1312").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="TRUE"
    Range("$A$1:$X$131").Select
     'here's where you select filtered results...
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Broken Justification").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

So filter for the rows you want, then just copy them all and paste them into your destination.

Comment: Yes, that can be done, but in my case, i want to copy only the new rows that i haven't copyied before on the previous database.
The database is incremental and after i copy the data to the new sheet, i treat the data with other script. 
So, to copy all of it again would make it double work and possible confusion on the data that is inserted manually to each specific row daily.